# UIPageControl for Swiping Only

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I am using a UIPageControl connected to a paging UIScrollView (all programmatically). I want to *only* allow the user to swipe through the pages.

The UIPageControl currently properly updates in the UIScrollViewDelegate's `scrollViewDidScroll`. However when you tap on the UIPageControl, the enabled dot jumps ahead one (which is the desired behavior for the home screen, etc but I do not want this tap to advance feature possible).

I want to prevent this behavior, but I can't find a way to easily disable it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pageControl.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: I found out that `pageControl.defersCurrentPageDisplay = true` also works, but this might have other side effects.